# Change document.getElementById in Javascript

Tags: javascript

Does anyone know how to change document.getElementById to something else, like $?

It would work like this:

```
$("theid")
```

instead of this:

```
document.getElementById("theid")
```

Comment: Just write a function and stick it in window['$']

Comment: You can use JQuery: http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function $(id){
  return document.getElementById(id);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
var $ = function(id){ 
     return document.getElementById(id);
}
```

Though I wouldn't advice it, `document.querySelector(All)` is more useful.

Answer (score 0):

```
function $(id) {
   return document.getElementById(id);
}
```

The dollar sign is a valid character to use as an identifier, so just declare a function with that as the name.

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function $(_i) {
                return document.getElementById(_i);
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="myDiv">Hello</div>
        <a href="javascript: alert($('myDiv').innerHTML)">Get InnerHTML</a>
    </body>
</html>
```